# How to use ListIterator with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, listiterator

I'm trying to loop through an ArrayList, Here my old code which gives error when trying to add new NPC

```
if (npcs != null && npcs.size() > 1) {
        for (NPC npc: npcs) {
            if (npc != null)
                if(npc.getShow())
                    npc.render(g);
        }
    }
```

So I tried turning that into a ListIterator to fix the issue,

```
private void render(Graphics g) {
listIter = npcs.listIterator();
        int index = 0;
            while(listIter.hasNext())
            {
                if(shouldAdd(index+1)) {
                    index++;
                    listIter.add(npcs.get(index));

                }

                NPC current = (NPC) listIter.next();
                if (current != null) {
                    if (current.getShow()) {
                        current.render(g);
                    }
                }
            }

}
    private boolean shouldAdd(int index) {
            if (npcs.size() > index) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Could someone please help me out and show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which error? Please show the stack trace.

Comment: I don't see how those 2 pieces of code are supposed to produce the same outcome. In the first you don't add anything at all and only iterate it and call the render method if certain criteria are fullfilled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: adding elements to a collection during iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993025/java-adding-elements-to-a-collection-during-iteration)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Use ListIterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437541/how-to-use-listiterator)