# Not getting the output of ListIterator

Tags: java, list

I was solving a problem in which I want to use the **ListIterator**, also, I have checked on google about ListIterator, but still, I am not getting the output. My code is as follows:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    //code
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int testCases = sc.nextInt();
    for(int testIndex=0;testIndex<testCases;testIndex++)
    {
        int size = sc.nextInt();
        List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
                int[] arrays = new int[size];
        for(int offset=0;offset<size;offset++)
        {
             al.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
                System.out.println(al);
                System.out.println();
        ListIterator lItr = al.listIterator();
                while(lItr.hasPrevious()){
                    System.out.print(lItr.previous()+" ");
                }
    }
}
```

My input is: 1(no. of test cases) 4(size of the array) 1 2 3 4(elements of the array)

And the output I am getting is : [1, 2, 3, 4]

It is not giving the output of previous ListIterator.

Comment: Are you trying to iterate elements in reverse order?  All iterators start at the beginning.

Comment: yes, I want to iterate the list in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `ListIterator` with `listIterator()`, the iterator is initialized to point to the start of the `List`. Therefore there is no previous element.

You can use `listIterator(int index)` to start iterating from an arbitrary position, and there will be a previous element.

To start iterating from the end of the `List`, use:

```
ListIterator<Integer> lItr = al.listIterator(al.size());
```

Comment: thank you, it worked on online compiler but it's not working on NetBeans ide. Also please refer to this link http://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/listiterator-example/ in this no size is mentioned in listIterator. According to you is that correct or not

Comment: @AsheeshSahu Your linked example starts from the beginning of the List (hence no parameter passed to the method), iterates forward over all the elements and then iterates backwards over all the elements. You only iterate backwards, so you must initialize the iterator to point to the end of the List. Perhaps the list was empty in your NetBeans attempt.

Comment: Means if don't want to pass the size of the list in listIterator then firstly I have to iterate the listIterator forward?

Answer (score 0):

`ListIterator` starts from the beginning of the list and doesn't have any previous element. Exact same problem is the following one. 
Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437541/how-to-use-listiterator).