# How to get current count in for loop using firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, loops, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase FireStore to retrive my all collections data
but i want to print Log of each 5 interwal how can i get the current count of the loop?

If any suggestion to change loop please also share your solution with code..

Here is my code

```
db
        .collection("news")
        .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .whereLessThan("timestamp",tm)
        .limit(10)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            for (doc in it) {
                val imgUrl = doc.getString("imageUrl")
                val heading = doc.getString("headline")
                val timestamp = doc.getTimestamp("timestamp")
                val tagline = doc.getString("tagline")
                val type = doc.getString("type")
                // position%5 but how to get the current position?
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for ((i, doc) in it.withIndex()) {
                val imgUrl = doc.getString("imageUrl")
                val heading = doc.getString("headline")
                val timestamp = doc.getTimestamp("timestamp")
                val tagline = doc.getString("tagline")
                val type = doc.getString("type")
                if(i%5==0) {
                    //add ur item
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The QuerySnapshot and its Iterator don't expose any index information as you iterate.  You would have to keep track of it yourself:

```
int i = 0
for (doc in it) {
    if (++i % 5 == 0) {
        // multiple of 5
    }
}
```

Or you can iterate a List of snapshots the you get from [getDocuments()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot#getDocuments()), [using its ListIterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437541/how-to-use-listiterator/43437755), which will expose indexes.